# $_POST dynamic name WITHOUT using foreach

Tags: php, post, dynamic

I'm trying to $_POST a dynamic name from an input in a phpmailer. I would like to get the value of a specific input that ends in a counter (e.g. productname1, productname2... where the number is dynamic and "productname" is static) I don't want to call these values one by one, since it would be redundant and ridiculous.

I've searched and all I seem to get is the solution that uses "foreach" and "key => $value". This doesn't work, since I'd like to create a table with 5 columns.

Instead of:

```
foreach($_POST as $pprice => $ppricevalue) {
if(strpos($pprice, 'Price/Unit') === 0) {
}}
```

I'd like something like:

```
$ppricevalue = $_POST[(strpos($pprice, 'Price/Unit') === 0)];
```

The latter is not valid.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT---------------------->

Cutting to the chase here, maybe posting the direct approach to what I want to accomplish might get me a good answer.

I've managed to dynamically create a table using div's and the "float:left" property to create a table using divs (not actually a table, but you get the point). It worked like a charm!. However, Microsoft and its capitalist monsters, in this case, Microsoft Outlook, strip away some html elements and most of the css. I bet if I use those ugly MSO classes, Outlook wouldn't strip or destroy my work.

This is the code. The trick is, how do you turn that into a table? A real html table?

```
$msg .="<div style='width:100%; white-space:nowrap; color:fff; font-weight:bold;'><div style='width:55%; background-color:#888; margin:0px; text-indent:10px;padding:10px 0px 10px 0px; float:left;'>Product Desc.</div><div style='width:10%;background-color:#888;  margin:0px; text-indent:10px;padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;float:left;'>Price</div><div style='width:6%;background-color:#888; margin:0px; text-indent:10px;padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;float:left;'>Qty</div><div style='width:14%;background-color:#888; margin:0px; text-indent:10px;padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;float:left;'>Core</div><div style='width:10%;background-color:#888; margin:0px; text-indent:10px;padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;float:left;'>Total</div></div>";



$msg .= "<div style='width:100%; margin:0px;'><div style='float:left; width:55%; white-space:normal;'>";
foreach($_POST as $product => $productvalue) {
if(strpos($product, 'Product#') === 0) {
    $msg .= "<div style='border:1px solid #ccc; padding:5px; font-size:12px; height:40px;'>" . $productvalue . "</div>";
}
}
$msg .= "</div>";
$msg .= "<div style='float:left; width:10%;'>";
foreach($_POST as $pprice => $ppricevalue) {
if(strpos($pprice, 'Price/Unit') === 0) {
    $msg .= "<div style='border:1px solid #ccc; padding:5px; font-size:12px; height:40px;'>" . $ppricevalue . "</div>";
}
}
$msg .= "</div>";

$msg .= "<div style='float:left; width:6%;'>";
foreach($_POST as $quantity => $quantityvalue) {
if(strpos($quantity, 'Quantity') === 0) {
    $msg .= "<div style='border:1px solid #ccc; padding:5px; font-size:12px; height:40px;'>" . $quantityvalue . "</div>";
}
}
$msg .= "</div>";
$msg .= "<div style='float:left; width:14%;'>";
foreach($_POST as $core => $corevalue) {
if(strpos($core, 'Core') === 0) {
    $msg .= "<div style='border:1px solid #ccc; padding:5px; font-size:12px; height:40px;'>" . $corevalue . "</div>";
}
}
$msg .= "</div>";

$msg .= "<div style='float:left; width:10%;'>";
foreach($_POST as $total => $totalvalue) {
if(strpos($total, 'Sub') === 0) {
    $msg .= "<div style='border:1px solid #ccc; padding:5px; font-size:12px; height:40px;'>" . $totalvalue . "</div>";
}
}


$msg .= "<hr><div style='float:left; margin-left:-140%; overflow:visible; font-size:12px; line-height:2.1em;'>Net Total:</div><div style='border:1px solid #ccc; padding:5px; font-size:12px; height:13px;'>" . $nettotal . "</div>";
$msg .= "<div style='float:left; margin-left:-140%; overflow:visible;font-size:12px;line-height:2.1em;'>State Tax:</div><div style='border:1px solid #ccc; padding:5px; font-size:12px; height:13px;'>" . $statetaxtotal . "</div>";
$msg .= "<div style='float:left; margin-left:-140%; overflow:visible; font-size:12px;line-height:2.1em;'>Municipal Tax:</div><div style='border:1px solid #ccc; padding:5px; font-size:12px; height:13px;'>" . $municipaltaxtotal . "</div>";



$msg .= "<hr><div style='float:left; margin-left:-140%; overflow:visible;'><b>Grand Total:</b></div><div style='float:left; width:100%;'><div style='border:1px solid #ccc; padding:5px; font-size:12px; height:13px;'>" . $grandtotal . "</div>";
$msg .= "</div></div>";
$msg .= "</div></div>";
```

Thanks for your quick responses!

Comment: What about http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php?

Comment: Can you change the HTML? You might consider using input arrays like `productname[]`. See [html arrays @ php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's exactly what you need, but maybe that could work ?

```
$dynamic = count($_POST);
if (isset($_POST['productname'.$dynamic])) {
    $ppricevalue = $_POST['productname'.$dynamic]['Price/Unit'];
}
```

Comment: This will count all `$_POST` elements; not necessarily `productname` elements.